# Will self be retained when send message to it

Tags: ios, objective-c

`TestObj` class is a simple class that has a method `doSomethingInBackground` in which I send it `performSelectorInBackground` method to make itself sleep 5 seconds in background thread.

```
@implementation TestObj

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%@, is main thread %u", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [NSThread isMainThread]) ;
}

- (void)doSomethingInBackground
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundWork) withObject:nil] ;
}

- (void)backgroundWork
{
    sleep(5) ;
}

@end
```

I alloc and init the instance and send it `doSomethingInBackground` message and assign `nil` to it in order to release it as soon as possible.

```
TestObj *obj = [[TestObj alloc] init] ;
[obj doSomethingInBackground] ;
obj = nil ;
```

I find that the `dealloc` will run after about 5 seconds `obj = nil;`, it seems that system retains `self` when send it the method `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundWork) withObject:nil] ;` and after `backgroundWork` returned, the instance will be deallocated.

Can anyone tell me the works that system do behind this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-[NSObject performSelectorInBackground:withObject:]` under the hood calls `-[NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]` which does retain the original receiver (here passed as `target` parameter)

NSThread documentation: "The objects target and argument are retained during the execution of the detached thread. They are released when the thread finally exits."

Comment: If I change `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundWork) withObject:nil]` to `[self performSelector:@selector(backgroundWork) withObject:nil afterDelay:5]` and do nothing in `backgroundWork` method, the result is the same. So I think it is not the main reason.

Comment: @KudoCC `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` retains the receiver directly. After calling the selector, the receiver is released through `CFRunLoopTimerInvalidate`. So I assume `-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:]` schedules a timer to delay the method call. Timers retain their targets. You can investigate this easily by disabling ARC, overloading `-retain` and `-release` methods in `TestObj` and setting breakpoints in them. (you can run this https://gist.github.com/bartekchlebek/c36dba5d41bbe7b6fb5e )

Answer (score 2):

From the Docs,

The `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` method creates a new detached thread and uses the specified method as the entry point for the new thread. For example, if you have some object (represented by the variable myObj) and that object has a method called doSomething that you want to run in a background thread, you could use the following code to do that:

```
[myObj performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil];
```

The effect of calling this method is the same as if you called the `detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` method of `NSThread` with the current object, selector, and parameter object as parameters. The new thread is spawned immediately using the default configuration and begins running.

In the detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject: documentation,

> The objects aTarget and anArgument are retained during the execution
>   of the detached thread, then released. The detached thread is exited
>   (using the exit class method) as soon as aTarget has completed
>   executing the aSelector method.

Regarding the performSelector:AfterDelay: ,

> This method sets up a timer to perform the aSelector message on the
>   current thread’s run loop. The timer is configured to run in the
>   default mode (NSDefaultRunLoopMode). When the timer fires, the thread
>   attempts to dequeue the message from the run loop and perform the
>   selector. It succeeds if the run loop is running and in the default
>   mode; otherwise, the timer waits until the run loop is in the default
>   mode

And

> The timer maintains a strong reference to this object until it (the
>   timer) is invalidated.

If you do not want your Obj to be retained, you can use a weak referenced object,

```
 TestObj *obj = [[TestObj alloc] init] ;
 __weak typeof(obj) weakObj = obj;
 [weakObj doSomethingInBackground] ;
 obj = nil ;
```

Comment: did you mean `[weakObj doSometingInBackground]`? Currently, there's no much point in creating `weakObj` since it's unused.

Comment: Thanks, both of you are right, I accept the one answered faster :)

Answer (score 1):

While special cases like `performSelector:` have been discussed in other answers I think it's helpful to add the answer to the general case:

> Will self be retained when send message to it

No. In both manual retain count and ARC `self` is never implicitly retained. You must take care that the receiver of a message is not deallocated during method execution.

While under ARC `self`'s type is strong the object is not actually retained. See the [ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#self).

Comment: Thanks for the answer in general case and the very useful documentation.